# Adding Map Service Geoprocessing Widget Results Web App

Tags: javascript, geoprocessing, arcgis-web-appbuilder, widget

I have a Web Appbuilder Application using several geoprocessing widgets that have extremely varied result values depending on what the user inputs. Therefore, I would like to symbolize the results with a Map Service, since that is flexible enough to apply unique symbology to the varying range of values.

However, I would like the user to be able to run the tools multiple times without the results getting replaced, as well as automatically enabling the pop-up, as you can do when you are viewing the results with AGOL symblology for the output. The Map service results do not give the option to add the layer to map, does not have the functionality to automatically enable the pop-up, and does not give the option to export results.

I feel stuck between choosing accurate/flexible symbology by viewing the results with a Map Service, and being able to configure a pop-up, download, and add multiple results to the web app session without it. I have looked at the below link, but have not been able to get my application to work.

http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/using-result-map-service-in-web-applications.htm

Do I put the code inside each geoprocessing widget? at the bottom? how can I keep multiple Map Service results at once?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a limitation of the Geoprocessing Widget of the WAB. You'd need to either extend this widget or build your own to handle the use case of multiple layers + popups.

From the [help here](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-geoprocessing.htm) the popup configuration happens when you return the features. You could perhaps return both features and map image, but I'm not sure that'll do what you want.